# Would distilling a sodium fluoride solution generate hydrogen fluoride to any noticeable extent?

Tags: acid-base, water, ionic-compounds, distillation

If  you have a solution of  NaF,  and  you boil  it (to  get  pure water by distillation)  can the  fluoride ions in water  separate  from  sodium ions and  combine with  hydrogen ions to form HF?    If yes,  how much of the molecules vaporized  is pure water and how  much is  HF?

Comment: The solubility of sodium fluoride in water is about 40 g/L. Distill off enough water and sodium fluoride will start to precipitate. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

For all intents and purposes, you can consider a solution of sodium fluoride that of a weak base in water. Remember the formula to calculate an acid constant $K_\mathrm{a}$:

$$\begin{gather}\ce{HF + H2O <=> F- + H3O+}\tag{1}\\
K_a = \frac{[\ce{F-}][\ce{H3O+}]}{[\ce{HF}]}\tag{2}\end{gather}$$

For convenience, the acid constant is typically given in logarithmic form as $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_fluoride) gives us the following value for $\ce{HF}$:

$$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} (\ce{HF}) = 3.17\tag{3}$$

If we use equations $(2)$ and $(4)$ (the ion product of water) plus a little maths, that allows us to calculate the concentration of $\ce{HF}$ under the assumption of a certain initial amount of $\ce{NaF}$ (e.g. $1~\mathrm{mol\cdot l^{-1}}$). $c_0$ is my notation for the inital concentration (i.e. before any changes).

$$\begin{align}K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H3O+}][\ce{OH-}] &= 10^{-14}~\mathrm{mol^2 \cdot l^{-2}}\tag{4}\\
\Longrightarrow c_0(\ce{H3O+}) &= 10^{-7}~\mathrm{mol\cdot l^{-1}}\tag{4'}\end{align}$$

From equation $(1)$, we can derive equations $(5)$ and $(6)$, linking together our unknowns to give us the big picture:

$$\begin{align}[\ce{H3O+}] &= c_0(\ce{H3O+}) - [\ce{HF}]\tag{5}\\
[\ce{HF}] &= c_0(\ce{F-}) - [\ce{F-}]\tag{6}\\
[\ce{H3O+}] &= c_0(\ce{H3O+}) - c_0(\ce{F-}) + [\ce{F-}]\tag{5'}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}K_\mathrm{a} &= \frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{F-}]}{[\ce{HF}]}\tag{7.1}\\
K_\mathrm{a} [\ce{HF}] &= [\ce{H3O+}][\ce{F-}]\tag{7.2}\\
K_\mathrm{a} \left(c_0(\ce{F-}) - [\ce{F-}]\right) &= \left(c_0(\ce{H3O+}) - c_0(\ce{F-}) + [\ce{F-}]\right) [\ce{F-}]\tag{7.3}
\end{align}$$

Henceforth, any $c_0$ appearing will be $c_0(\ce{F-})$ and $c_0(\ce{H3O+})$ will be replaced by $10^{-7}$ — ignoring the unit.

$$\begin{align}K_\mathrm{a}c_0 - K_\mathrm{a}[\ce{F-}] &= 10^{-7}[\ce{F-}] - c_0[\ce{F-}] + [\ce{F-}]^2\tag{7.4}\\
0 &= [\ce{F-}]^2 + \left(10^{-7} - c_0 + K_\mathrm{a}\right)[\ce{F-}] - K_\mathrm{a}c_0\tag{7.5}\end{align}$$

Thankfully, the equation is quadratic and we can solve it for $[\ce{F-}]_{1/2}$:

$$\begin{align}[\ce{F-}]_{1/2} &= \frac{- \left(10^{-7} - c_0 + K_\mathrm{a}\right) \pm \sqrt{\left(10^{-7} - c_0 + K_\mathrm{a}\right)^2 + 4 K_\mathrm{a}c_0}}{2}\tag{8.1}\\
[\ce{F-}]_{1/2} &= \frac{1 - 10^{-7} - 10^{-3.17} \pm \sqrt{\left(10^{-7} - 1 + 10^{-3.17}\right)^2 + 4 \times 10^{-3.17}}}{2}\tag{8.2}\\
[\ce{F-}]_{1/2} &= \frac{ 0.9993 \pm \sqrt{0.9986 +0.0027}}{2}\tag{8.3}\\
[\ce{F-}]_{1/2} &= \frac{ 0.9993 \pm \sqrt{1.0013}}{2}\tag{8.4}\\
[\ce{F-}]_{1/2} &= \frac{ 0.9993 \pm 1.0006}{2}\tag{8.5}\end{align}$$

As always, we need to perform a reality check. Subtracting is obviously not an option, as it would lead to a negative concentration. Thus we must add.

$$\begin{align}[\ce{F-}] &= \frac{ 0.9993 + 1.0006}{2}\tag{8.6}\\
[\ce{F-}] &= \frac{1.9999998}{2}\tag{8.7}\\
[\ce{F-}] &= 0.9999999\tag{8.8}\end{align}$$

So of the $1~\mathrm{mol \cdot l^{-1}}$ solution of sodium fluoride we have, a $10^{-7}~\mathrm{mol \cdot l^{-1}}$ solution of $\ce{HF}$ will result. (By the way, the units check out; we do indeed get $\mathrm{mol \cdot l^{-1}}$ at the end.)

You get similar results at other concentrations; if your initial fluoride concentration was $10^{-3}~\mathrm{mol \cdot l^{-1}}$, the resulting $\ce{HF}$ concentration will be $5.966 \times 10^{-8}~\mathrm{mol \cdot l^{-1}}$. There is no need to fear (or hope for) any $\ce{HF}$ development during distillation.